# Why must end be greater than start for a JodaTime BaseInterval?

Tags: java, jodatime

I can understand why in most cases it is proper to enforce that an end time be greater than a start time, but is there a specific reason why the JodaTime library enforces that constraint on the BaseInterval type?

This is really hampering my ability to design a time machine which can also travel backwards in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is not possible to finish something before you start it.

Time is incrementing in the JodaTime measurement system.  This means that all times are ordered such that smaller times are "before" larger times.  The "start" time of something thus is guaranteed to be less than or equal to it's "end" time.

As for design reasons, it greatly simplifies the math.  In order to compare if two times overlap, one can simplify the comparisons based on assumptions that the start time is before the end time.   Without such assumptions, one would have to detect the "direction" of a time interval and possibly get it's "reverse direction" to detect overlap in the same manner.

Since time intervals can be combined in such a way that one obtains the bounding interval of two intervals, intervals that contain non-like directions break the mathematical assumptions.  For example, what is the direction of the bounds of an interval that contains both forward and backward time directions?  I supposed one could come up with a "mixed" direction, but that further complicates the math with three states for interval direction.

Likewise, denying the calculation of a bounding interval when it's components are in a mixed direction complicates the interface for all of the ordinary use cases.  A clean, concise set based math on intervals would have to somehow cleanly incorporate direction.

Comment: Thank you for that edit, which clarified a great deal more.

Comment: @Greg Thank you for the kind words.  The statements are simple, but the implications often are not.  I've dealt (and written) time systems that handled intervals in the past.  Joda's decision to have time unidirectional is why the intervals as a set of instants system works intuitively.  You're need for bidirectional times intrigues me.  For the interval as a set to work correctly, one needs bidirectional instants.  I might have to attempt modeling the existence of the milk in "Fortunately, the Milk"

Comment: @Greg From a purely narrative scenario, most time travel is modeled as "jumping" backwards to a new point where you move forward.  In such jumps, they tend to be instantaneous.  In reality, if something moved backwards, and from a frame of reference within still had a forward arrow of time, wouldn't it immediately collide with itself?  Might want to consider that and design in some safety mechanism for your time machine :)

Comment: In all seriousness, the "jump" is what I am grappling with.  I was hoping that Interval was modeled as a time vector (origin with a magnitude and direction).  In that case, a jump can be modeled as series of one or more Intervals.  For me, the journey influences which destination is arrived at.  In other words, one interval may be a function of another, or each interval may be influenced by another process.  To jump into the past, I would model the travel as a collection of Intervals with negative Duration.  The jump is in terms of Duration and the actual destination depends on the origin.

Comment: @Greg so in seriousness, a vector has a magnitude, but what you have in JodaTime is that magnitude being the "normal" of the "time distance" in a direction.  That means a vector representing a movie showtime which is four times longer than another vector representing a different movie showtime models a movie that takes four times longer to play than another.  It doesn't "hold" displacement in time without displacement.  If you perceive jumps as "instantaneous" (taking no time) then perhaps you can model it with a list of forward time vectors.

Comment: @Greg For example, a person walking backwards could be conceived as a person walking forwards with a negative time vector.  It seems that's not what you are talking about.  It seems you are talking about a list (ordered) of time events that, while each time event is ordered (start and end) the overall time list isn't.  Some starts will be before other starts, and some ends might even terminate in the middle of other time events.  This would allow modeling like described in "Fortunately, the Milk" where the characters unexpectedly see themselves only to know why later.

Comment: Yes, eventually I want to be able to take two "Jump" objects, with the same origin but with different destinations, and merge them to create a third Jump whose destination is not necessarily the sum of the two.  For example, overlapping time in Intervals would only be counted once.  Merging might then be implemented as various flavors of set joins.  Or even more obscurely, based on rules given who is doing the jump, and maybe even what kind of jump (great as a leap, perhaps just a hop).  For example, leaps and hops might have some kind of interaction between them differently than two hops.

Comment: @Greg The book reference is a bit of fun, but it is serious too.  It's likely a more accurate picture of what time travel _might_ look like in a frame of reference of the traveler.  If one traveled back and met themselves, then they would always have an unexplained meeting of themselves, which they would later discover to be explained by their own actions.  This idea is also used comedically in "Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure" where, despite being reminded by their future selves, they don't wind their watch (which leads to them reminding themselves).

Comment: @Greg Effectively, you would have to have two frames of "time" reference, the world (JodaTime) and the traveler (the linked list).  It probably is problematic, but so is the concept of time travel in reverse.